# DB2 Import (Raw) XML Data

Tags: xml, import, db2, load, db2-luw

Is there a way to import (or load) raw xml data into a table with a column of type xml.

```
<customerinfo Cid="1000"><name>Kathy Smith</name><addr country="Canada"><street>5 Rosewood</street><city>Toronto</city><prov-state>Ontario</prov-state><pcode-zip>M6W 1E6</pcode-zip></addr><phone type="work">416-555-1358</phone></customerinfo>
<customerinfo Cid="1001"><name>Kathy Smith</name><addr country="Canada"><street>25 EastCreek</street><city>Markham</city><prov-state>Ontario</prov-state><pcode-zip>N9C 3T6</pcode-zip></addr><phone type="work">905-555-7258</phone></customerinfo>
...
```

Each Row of the xml Document should be place in a row.

```
import from C:\temp\test.xml OF DEL INSERT INTO XMLCOLUMN
```

DB2 reads the XML file correct but failes to import it into the rows...

```
Number of rows read = 6
Number of rows skipped = 0
Number of rows inserted = 0
Number of rows updated = 0
Number of rows rejected = 6
Number of rows = 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One idea might be to check the actual error messages explaining exactly _why_ those rows were rejected.

Comment: I basicly says it it missing a xsd file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a DEL file containing a description of where to find the XML file or files. Try something like:

test.del:

```
<XDS FIL='test.xml' />
```

If you have additional columns, the above XDS would be a regular column value next to the other values.

test.xml: your XML file

Then

```
import from test.del OF DEL INSERT INTO MyTable
```

"MyTable" is your table with the XML column. See the [DB2 docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) for more examples.

Comment: yeah saidly there is no option to import raw xml data... but thanks.

Comment: You can import raw XML, but need to go through the CSV file workaround. I have seen scripts that can generate the CSV if you only want to import XML data.